# Multiple parents with the same class with siblings with the same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="example">
  <div class="test">Some text</div>
  <div class="whatever"></div>
</div>

<div class="example">
  <div class="test">Some more text</div>
  <div class="whatever"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make each `.example`'s `.whatever` contain the contents of its `.test`?

For example, if the code were just this:

```
<div class="example">
  <div class="test">Some text</div>
  <div class="whatever"></div>
</div>
```

Then I could just do this:

```
$('.whatever').text($('.test').text());
```

But I have multiple elements with the class `.whatever` and multiple elements with the class `.test`, and each `.test` contains different text.

So in other words, how can I make every element with the class `.whatever` contain the text of the element `.test`, but only the element `.test` that is in the sample `.example` element?

Sorry for the confusing wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.example').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.whatever').html( $(this).find('.test').html() );
});​
```

[Tested Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8JCXD/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".whatever").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).siblings(".test").text());
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YXf5C/